# Override Vue's mixin method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to override some of npm's mixin which is called inside the component by the local one ?

I have an npm package component inside
`node_modules/somePackageName/components/footer.vue` which use another of it's mixins from
`node_modules/somePackageName/mixins/popup.js`

That `popup.js` contains following method:

```
methods: {
  setPopupActiveStatus (val, blur = true) {
    const isVisible = false
  }
},
```

And I want to override it's behaviour from `App.vue` where I use that `footer.vue` component with something like this:

```
methods: {
  setPopupActiveStatus (val, blur = true) {
    const isVisible = true
  }
},
```

But it doesn't work as I wanted to.

**==== UPDATE ====**

Here is the explanation of How I solved my issue based on @Estradiaz's answer:

[image]

Comment: cant you just `class ExtendedComp extends Original{setPopupActiveStatus (val, blur = true) {
   //this.super();\n
    const isVisible = true;
  }}`?

Comment: @Estradiaz - I think it's a to high level of JS for me to understand the implementation of your code without an example.

Comment: aspirinemaga, could you get the example ball rolling with a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) or a little more description of your issue?

Comment: @aspirinemaga my bad i am way to much in the space of typescript - but the basic idea is like https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend , `Vue.extend(OriginalCompOption).extend(changes)` or `OriginalComp.extend(changes)` depends on the export in footer.vue, actually its the same as `ClonedOriginalComp.mixins.push(changes)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Where Vue extends

So basically what you want to do is to extend your current component by a custom method.
This can be done with `Vue.extend`. Vue provides an option to worryless clone/extend components by assigning one component to the `extends` option:

[Option/ Composition - extends](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends)

```
import SourceComponent from 'node_modules/somePackageName/components/footer.vue'
export default {
   name: "override",
   extends: SourceComponent,
   methods: {
      thatActualMethodBehaviour(){}
   }
}
```

---

[Vue.extend](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend)

```
// can be  Function | Object
import SourceComponent from 'node_modules/somePackageName/components/footer.vue'
if(typeof SourceComponent === 'function'){
  export default SourceComponent.extend({
      methods: {thatActualMethodBehaviour(){}}
  })
} else {
  export default Vue.extend(SourceComponent).extend({
      methods: {thatActualMethodBehaviour(){}}
  })  
}
```

[Option/ Composition - mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mixins)

```
// must be Object
import SourceComponentOption from 'node_modules/somePackageName/components/footer.vue'
if(typeof SourceComponent !== 'function'){
  export default Vue.extend({
      mixins: [SourceComponentOption],
      methods: {thatActualMethodBehaviour(){}}
  })
}
```

---

the - Y U DO DIS ?!?? - path

```
import SourceComponentOption from 'node_modules/somePackageName/components/footer.vue'
export default Object.assign({}, SourceComponentOption, {methods: Object.assign({}, SourceComponentOption.methods, {thatActualMethodBehaviour: function(){}}))
```

---

typescript: [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)

```
import {Vue, Component} from 'vue-property-decorator'
import SourceComponent from 'node_modules/somePackageName/components/footer.vue'
@Component<CustomComponent>({...hooks})
export default class CustomComponent extends SourceComponent{
   methods: thatActualMethodBehaviour(){}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! First solution, https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends approach helped me to solve the problem. What I've understood is that if you want to override a mixin, you should do it in a caller component, so I had to clone a `footer.vue` and then `popup.vue` where `popup.js` where called.

Comment: @aspirinemaga You are welcome, ___ i am not sure if i understand **"footer.vue and then popup.vue where popup.js where called"** but to have `name.vue` && `name.js` feels kinda redundant

Comment: please check my Question post after UPDATED section for better explanation.

Answer (score 5):

### When [combining mixin & component options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging):

> *When a mixin and the component itself contain overlapping options, they will be "merged" using appropriate strategies:*
>
> - **Data objects** undergo a recursive merge, with the component’s data taking priority in cases of conflicts.
> - **Hook functions** with the same name are merged into an array so that all of them will be called. Mixin hooks will be called before the component’s own hooks.
> - **Methods**, **Components** and **Directives** will be merged into the same object. The component’s options will take priority when there are conflicting keys in these objects.

Here's an example of a method provided by both a component and a mixin:

```js
var mixin = {
  methods: {
    foo: function () {
      console.log('Mixin Msg')
    },
  }
}

var vm = new Vue({
  mixins: [mixin],
  methods: {
    foo: function () {
      console.log('Component Msg')
    },
  }
})

vm.foo() // => "Component Msg"
```

And here's an [**example in codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-c0p9b)

So I believe you should be able to "override" the mixin simply by providing a method with the same name on the component and it will take priority

Comment: That's what I did, I tried to **override** mixins method by simply redefining a method with the same name inside the caller's methods. Same as your example, but all it does it calls old mixin method with a newly defined method inside the component, instead of replacing it.